# Expectation of a sequence of binary random variables with memory

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, expected-value

Consider a random sequence of ones and zeroes (successes and failures) $x_0,x_1,x_2...$ defined as follows. There is another sequence $c_0,c_1,c_2...$ which counts the number of successive failures. If $x_n=0$ (failure), then $c_{n+1}=c_{n}+1$. If $x_n=1$ (success), then $c_{n+1}=0$. $c_0=0$

The value of $x_n$ simply follows a Bernoulli distribution that succeeds with probability $f(c_n)$, where $f$ is some function whose outputs are all between 0 and 1.

Given $f$, is there an easy way to find the expectation of $x_n$ in the long run that doesn't involve simulating the process or using brute force? Please also provide an example.

Comment: I imagine the expectation doesn't exist in general, because one could arrange the sequence $x_0$ to consist with high likelihood of constant subsequences of ever-increasing length. For example, take $f(k)=1-1/k^9$, except if $k=j!$ for some $j$, in which case take $f(k)=1/(k\log k)$ ... some variant of this should work.

Comment: This is a Markov Chain with state space $\{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$, where each state can transition only to the next state or back to $0$, right?  Abstractly speaking, you can write the (infinite) transition matrix and try to find the steady state distribution, which should give you $E[x_\infty]$.  If your $f$ has additional structure, this may be practically doable...

Comment: @GregMartin I'm not sure if I understand you correctly and I'm not that good with random sequences but I don't think that's possible. Every time there is a success the memory is completely wiped, so subsequences of ever-increasing length won't happen I think. Also the example you gave wouldn't work because the function isn't defined at k=0. Again I'm not very confident that I know what you're talking about

Comment: @antkam Thank you for the connection! Additionally, the state space would be finite if there was any non-negative integer value of $k$ where $f(k)=1$. I have no idea how hard it is to find the steady state distribution of a Markov chain but I'll google it.

Comment: You're right that I didn't understand it resets itself at every success. (That $f$ isn't defined at $k=0$ isn't a serious obstacle in and of itself, since the function was meant to be suggestive rather than the exact formula.)

Comment: At any time $n$ for which $c_n=0$, the probability that the next success happens at time $n+k$ ($k\ge0$) is exactly $(1-f(0))(1-f(1))\cdots(1-f(k-1))f(k)$. So isn't the expectation of $x_n$ going to be the reciprocal of the expected number of steps between successes, or $$\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(1-f(0))(1-f(1))\cdots(1-f(k-1))f(k)\bigg)^{-1}\;?$$

Comment: @GregMartin - I think you're right!  You should write that up as an Answer.

Comment: @GregMartin Just one small error. "$(1-f(0))(1-f(1))\cdots(1-f(k-1))f(k)$" is the formula for the probability that the next success happens at time $n+k+1$. The probability that the next success happens at time $n+k$ is $(1-f(0))(1-f(1))\cdots(1-f(k-2))f(k-1)$. You can check this yourself, but basically it's because $x_n$ depends on $c_{n-1}$, not $c_{n}$. If you update your formula to account for this and post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it!

Comment: You explicitly describe how $c_{n+1}$ depends on $x_n$, that is, $c_n$ depends on $x_{n-1}$. Are you saying that $x_n$ depends on $c_{n-1}$ as well? That would mean that there are two completely disconnected processes going on—the "$x_{even}$-and-$c_{odd}$" process and the "$x_{odd}$-and-$c_{even}$" process.

Comment: @GregMartin My bad! What I meant was that $c_n$ describes $x_{n-1}$. Your first formula (the one without the sum) is the correct formula for the probability that the next success is at time $n+k$ if $c_n=0$. The problem is that you interpret the next success being at $n+k$ to mean that there are $k$ steps in between successes. However, since $c_n=0$ if $x_{n-1}$ is a success, that means there are actually $(n+k)-(n-1)=k+1$ steps in between successes, so your final formula still needs updating. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Think I got it right now....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any time $n$ for which $c_n$ equals $0$ (meaning that $x_{n-1}=1$, or $n=0$), the probability that the next success happens at time $n+k$ (for any $k\ge0$) is $\big( 1-f(0) \big)\big( 1-f(1) \big)\cdots \big( 1-f(k-1) \big) f(k)$. Therefore the expectation of $x_n$ is asymptotically equal to the reciprocal of the expectation of the number of time steps from one success to the next, or in other words
$$
\bigg( \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) \big( 1-f(0) \big)\big( 1-f(1) \big)\cdots \big( 1-f(k-1) \big) f(k) \bigg)^{-1} = \bigg( \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) f(k) \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \big( 1-f(j) \big) \bigg)^{-1} .
$$